# Android Two different AsyncTask and that have different putParcelableArrayList then how to Intent together

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask, bundle

**1. here my Order of execution**

SplashActivity : two AsyncTask (each have different result and I want to Intent to next Activity when each AsyncTask Parsing and putParcelableArrayList completed.

MainActivity : getParrcelableArrayList from SplashActivity

In addition

-already implemented parcelable in the model class.

-The values ​​in the array are well stored.

**2. my Answer**

how to Intent and startActivity when each AsyncTask complated putParcelableArrayList

please, need your help!!
if you don't unberstand, write comment please!

Comment: execute your asynctask one by one and when the second one completes, combine your parcelable data in a single intent and pass it to the next activity

Comment: so you want to pass intent only when both the asynctask completes, right?

Comment: @KiranMalvi your right, I want to execute each put Values in Parcelable Array in AsyncTask when it completed, startActivity to next Activity at once.

Comment: @VivekMishra
how to combine my parcelable data in a single intent?
Could you show me an example?

Comment: keep a global reference of your parcelable list from your first asynctask and use it in your second asynctask'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible ways to achieve this,
one way, you can call second AsyncTask in `onPostExecute` of first one, and then call the intent from `onPostExecute` of second.

Another way is you can call some common method which will set two `boolean` global parameters, on completion of first AsyncTask make one `boolean` true on same way for another and once both values are true you can call intent from that method.

Comment: here is my code!
first please check my put and get bundle.
Is it right code that put and get parcelable value?

[SplashActivitiy]
Bundle dailyBundle = new Bundle();
dailyBundle.putParcelableArrayList("dailyRank", mDailyItem);

[MainActivity]
Bundle dailyBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
mDailyItem = dailyBundle.getParcelableArrayList("dailyRank");

and In order your comment
1. second AsyncTask inside First AsyncTask in onPostExecute
2. two of them check completaion each Asynctask status. if both values are ture, call intent

right?
I'm sorry that my english is not well.

Comment: Thank You for answer!!
I solved the problem through your answers. 
[There are two possible ways to achieve this, one way, you can call second AsyncTask in onPostExecute of first one, and then call the intent from onPostExecute of second.]